Error in apollo client with refresh token code
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';
import possibleTypes from './src/possibleTypes.json';
import Events from 'react-native-simple-events';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import {
  callBackFetch
} from './src/Helpers';
import { TokenRefreshLink } from 'apollo-link-token-refresh';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import { REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN } from './src/API/Auth';
import { store } from './src/Store';
import { updateAccessToken, updateRefreshToken } from './src/Actions/Global';
import Config from 'react-native-config';

export const getCurrentUrl = () => {
  return Config.GRAPHQL_URL;
};

/* global __DEV__ */

export const accessTokenExpired = async () => {
  let token = await store.getState()?.globalReducer?.accessToken;
  if (!token) return true;
  const { exp } = jwtDecode(token);
  const expires = exp * 1000;
  if (new Date().getTime() >= (expires - (20 * 1000 * 60))) return false;
  return true;
};

export const updateUserTokens = async userTokensData => {
  let { accessToken, refreshToken } = userTokensData;
  await store.dispatch(updateAccessToken(accessToken));
  await store.dispatch(updateRefreshToken(refreshToken));
};

const Connect = () => {
  const httpLink = new createUploadLink({ uri: getCurrentUrl() });
  let version = DeviceInfo.getVersion();

  const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    const token = store?.getState()?.globalReducer?.accessToken;

    if (
      token ||
      operation?.operationName === 'signIn' ||
      operation?.operationName === 'verifyOTP' ||
      operation?.operationName === 'truecallerLogin'
    ) {
      // if (__DEV__) {
      //   console.log('token', token)
      // }
      operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          'apollo-require-preflight': true,
          authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null,
        },
      }));

      return forward(operation).map(resp => {
        let { data = {} } = resp;
        if (data?.errors) {
          errorHandling(data.errors);
        } else if (
          data?.validateOtp ||
          data?.signUpUser ||
          data?.restoreAccount ||
          data?.updateProfile ||
          data?.refreshAccessToken ||
          data?.truecallerLogin
        ) {
          const responseData = data?.validateOtp || data?.signUpUser || data?.restoreAccount || data?.updateProfile || data?.refreshAccessToken || data?.truecallerLogin;
          updateUserTokens(responseData);
        }
        return resp;
      });
    } else {
      client.clearStore();
    }
  });

  const logoutEvent = () => {
    if (
      store.getState()?.globalReducer?.accessToken &&
      store.getState()?.globalReducer?.refreshToken
    ) {
      client.clearStore();
      Events.trigger('logoutuser');
    }
  };

  const refreshTokenQuery = async () => {
    const refreshToken = store?.getState()?.globalReducer?.refreshToken;

    if (!refreshToken) {
      logoutEvent();
      return;
    }
    const response = await callBackFetch({ QueryRequest: REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN, token: refreshToken });
    const data = response?.data || {};

    if (!data || !data?.refreshAccessToken) {
      logoutEvent();
      return;
    }
    await updateUserTokens(data);
  };

  const refreshTokenLink = new TokenRefreshLink({
    accessTokenField: 'refreshAccessToken',
    isTokenValidOrUndefined: async () => accessTokenExpired(),
    fetchAccessToken: refreshTokenQuery, // Reference the async function
    handleFetch: async data => {
      if (data?.accessToken && data?.refreshToken) {
        await updateUserTokens(data);
      }
    },
    handleResponse: async (res) => {
      if (res?.errors) {
        if (res?.errors[0]?.extensions?.status === 401) {
          await refreshTokenQuery();
          return;
        }
        // Return other errors
        return res.errors;
      } else {
        return res.data;
      }
    },
    handleError: (error) => {
      // Handle unexpected errors during token refresh logic
      console.error('Error handling refresh token response:', error);
    },
  });

  const errorLink = onError(({ operation, graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
    if (__DEV__) {
      console.log('GQL error ', operation, JSON.stringify(graphQLErrors), networkError);
    }

    if (graphQLErrors?.length) {
      errorHandling(graphQLErrors);
    }
  });


  const errorHandling = (errorsArray) => {
    let errorObj = errorsArray;
    if (Array.isArray(errorsArray)) {
      errorObj = errorsArray[0];
      if (errorObj?.extensions?.status === 401) {
        if (errorObj?.message === 'Whatsapp authentication link expired.') {
          Toast.show(errorObj.message);
        }
        logoutEvent();
        return
      }
    }
    let errorMsg = errorObj.message;
    if (errorObj?.extensions?.originalError?.message) {
      errorMsg = errorObj?.extensions?.originalError?.message;
    }
    if (errorMsg == 'Nothing to change' || errorMsg === 'Test attempt is already complete') {
      // error message
    } else {
      Toast.show(errorMsg);
    }
  };

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([refreshTokenLink, authLink, errorLink, httpLink]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
      possibleTypes,
    }),
  });

  return client;
};
export default Connect;

This is my code as i am using apollo client refresh link.
As I am using this code. My token is expiring in 5 hours  and refresh token expires in 10 days. So what is happening in my react native app as I am opening my react native app on the next then I am getting an error not able to debug it. As the error is this with app crash
Error handling refresh token response: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'body.data')]
